# winsock errors visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winsock

I want to write an app which uses libcurl, I added the lib and without writing any code trying to compile it, it gives me some compiler errors

```
Fehler  79  error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winsock2.h    2461
Fehler  55  error C2375: 'shutdown': Neudefinition; unterschiedliche Bindung    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winsock2.h    1966
Fehler  114 error C2227: Links von "->imsf_interface" muss sich ein Zeiger auf Klassen-/Struktur-/Union-/generischen Typ befinden.  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h    773
Fehler  106 error C2065: 'Filter': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\ws2tcpip.h    766
```

in german they mean type newdefinition and the last one that some things are not declared, there are much more but they are the same, I also installed SDK from another post that wrote that it should fix problems with winsock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/af431084-0b0c-45a7-bdcf-bdf4bf07afcb/)

Hope this helps.